# Bash output error after execution completed?

Tags: python

I want to pass in a file name (`line` below), located within a text file (`f` below) into another program (`file.py` below), which takes in arguments with flags `-in_file` and `-out`. I keep getting this following error:

```
file.py: error: argument -in_file/--input_file_path: expected one argument
```

after I verify the complete execution of `file.py` as I want it to. I verified that the arguments are being passed into `file.py`, so why am I still getting this error saying that I didn't specify the argument?

```
with open(args['input_path'], 'r') as f:
   gVCF_dir = output_dir + '/gVCF'
   os.makedirs(gVCF_dir, exist_ok = True)   
   for line in f:
      tools_dir = '/some/path/'
      pipeline[0] = 'file.py'
      os.system('python3 ' + tools_dir + pipeline[0] + ' ' + '-in_file' + ' ' + line + ' -out' + ' ' + gVCF_dir)
```

For reference, here is the full error:

```
sh: line 1: -out: command not found
usage: file.py [-h] [-in_dir INPUT_DIRECTORY]
                          [-in_file INPUT_FILE_PATH] [-out OUTPUT_DIRECTORY]
                          [-L Desc1] [-n NUM_CORES]
                          [-t RUNTIME] [-p QUEUE] [--mem_per_cpu MEM_PER_CPU]
                          [--mail_type MAIL_TYPE] [--mail_user MAIL_USER]
                          [-overrides OVERRIDES_PATH]
file.py: error: argument -in_file/--input_file_path: expected one argument
sh: line 1: -out: command not found
```

There are default values for everything except `-in_file` and `-out`.

Comment: Not your immediate problem, but note that `os.system()` shouldn't be used -- it's much less reliable than using `subprocess.Popen()` with `shell=False`, insofar as the latter doesn't expose you to shell injection vulnerabilities when handling untrusted data.

Comment: Anyhow, `-out: command not found` is very clear; sounds like your `line` hasn't been stripped so it has a newline on the end, so it's being parsed by the shell (which you wouldn't have if you were doing it with `subprocess.Popen()`!) as syntax, such that you're running more than one command.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating? What do you mean my `line` hasn't been stripped?

Comment: When you read a line from a file in Python, it still has its trailing newline on the end of it. If you `print(repr(line))`, you'll see something like `'foo\n'`; the `\n` is the newline that terminates the line, separating it from later contents in the same file.

Comment: By contrast, `print(repr(line.strip()))` will be only `'foo'`, with the `\n` removed -- *stripped* from the content.

Comment: That fixed the first error; however, I still have the following error: `file.py: error: argument -in_file/--input_file_path: expected one argument`

Comment: A good place to start is adding `set -x;` before the rest of the command to turn on logging, so you can see what the shell started by `os.system()` is actually passing to the command it invokes in turn. (Though a *better* place to start would be following the advice you were given to *not use a shell*).